GMRES reducing Hessenberg
I am reading Saad and am trying to go through problems that have appeared on qualifying exams given at my school. This problem deals with GMRES algorithm using Arnoldi process, but with a different starting vector, i.e., $v_0 = r_0 = b-Ax_0$ and $v_1 = Av_0 / \|Av_0\|_2$.

Now in general, the Arnoldi process allows us to write $AV_m = V_{m+1}\bar{H}_{m}$, where the columns of $V_m$ form an orthonormal basis for $K_m(r_0) = \{r_0, Ar_0, \dots, A^{m-1}r_0\}$ and $\bar{H}_m$ is a $(m+1) \times m$ Hessenberg matrix.
How could we answer the first question for example. In general we know that we have the expansion $$Av_k = \sum_{i = 1}^{k+1} c_{ik}v_i,$$ but how can I show that in the case of selecting $v_1 = Ar_0 / \|Ar_0\|_2$ this reduces into a triangular system? In other words, the Hessenberg is replaced by a triangular matrix.

If we write $V_{m-1}:=[v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}]$, we have that $AV_{m-1}=V_m\bar{H}_{m-1}$ as in the standard Arnoldi process. Since the columns of $V_{m-1}$ form an orthonormal basis of $AK_{m-1}$ given the starting vector chosen, assuming we did not exhaust the Krylov subspace, the columns of $[v_0, V_{m-1}]$ provide a basis of $K_m$, though not necessarily (and actually very likely not) orthonormal.
As requested, we express the correction of $x_m$ in the basis $v_0,\ldots,v_{m-1}$:
$$
x_m = x_0+[v_0, V_{m-1}]c_m,
$$
where $c_m$ is a vector of coefficients to be determined.
The residual is then
$$
\begin{split}
r_m&=b-Ax_m=b-Ax_0-A[v_0,V_{m-1}]c_m\\&=r_0-[Av_0,AV_{m-1}]c_m
=r_0-[Av_0,V_m\bar{H}_{m-1}]c_m.
\end{split}
$$
By definition, $v_1=Av_0/\|Av_0\|_2$, so $Av_0=\|Av_0\|_2 v_1 = \|Av_0\|_2 V_m e_1$, where $e_1:=[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$, so we can write the residual as
$$
r_m=r_0-V_{m}[\|Av_0\|_2 e_1, \bar{H}_{m-1}]c_m=r_0-V_mU_mc_m.
$$
We can orthogonally decompose $r_0$ as $r_0=V_mV_m^Tr_0+(I-V_mV_m^T)r_0$ and have
$$
r_m=V_m(V_m^Tr_0-V_mU_mc_m) + (I-V_mV_m^T)r_0.
$$
Note that the two parts are mutually orthogonal, so
$$
\|r_m\|_2^2=\|V_m^Tr_0-U_mc_m\|_2^2+\|(I-V_mV_m^T)r_0\|_2^2
$$
Clearly, this is minimized if the first term is zero, that is, when
$$
U_mc_m=V_m^Tr_0=:d_m.
$$
Hence the coefficients $c_m$ are given by solving an upper triangular system with $U_m$.
For the residual, we have
$$
r_m=(I-V_mV_m^T)r_0,
$$
which is computable without knowing the approximate solution $x_m$. In fact, we can write the relation above as
$$
r_m=(I-v_mv_m^T)(I-V_{m-1}V_{m-1}^T)r_0=(I-v_mv_m^T)r_{m-1}.
$$
This then leads to a reccurence
$$
r_m=r_{m-1}-\alpha_m v_m, \quad \alpha_m:=v_m^Tr_{m-1}.
$$
By some extra thoughts, we can also find that the right hand side of the triangular system is in fact $d_m=[\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{m-1}]^T$, so no extra dot products are needed to form it.
This algorithm is known as Simpler GMRES.

Presumable, why would a solution exist to $U_mc_m = d_m$?

@DerpyPenguin $U_m$ is nonsingular if $r_0\neq 0$ and $\bar{H}{m-1}$ has full rank. If $m$ was the largest index for which the Arnoldi process does not break down, the affine space $x_0+\mathrm{colspan}([v_0, V{m-1}])$ would already contain the exact solution to $Ax=b$.
